# SQL Server Integration Services 2012 - Legacy deployment

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm currently reading a lot about SSIS and I have read that there are now two models for deploying a solution : the one using "Projects" and the one using "Packages".
Starting SQL Server 2012, a database generally called SSISDB can be created as the SSIS catalog. 
My question is the following: let's say that I have created the SSISDB but that I will use the legacy deployment model, will the package I deployed be found in the SSISDB ?

Thanks in advance.

Jeff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No<sup>*</sup>, it won't.

The Package Deployment Model, if deployed to the database, will store individual packages in msdb.dbo.syspackages90 (SQL Server 2005) and msdb.dbo.sysssispackages (SQL Server 2008+)

The Project Deployment Model, deploys to the SSISDB. There it takes the form of Folders/Projects/Packages which are stored in

- SSISDB.catalog.folders
- SSISDB.catalog.projects
- SSISDB.catalog.packages

<sup>*</sup>With the 2016 release of SQL Server, we now have incremental package deployment for SSIS projects using the project deployment model. Based on an early release candidate at least, this means you can keep your SSIS projects in the package deployment model yet deploy to the SSISDB to take advantage of the improved management, logging, configuration and execution there.